# добавить в форму MVC Spring кнопки с разными действиями

Tags: java, spring, mvc, jsp

Помогите с обучением хочу сделать две кнопки
есть jsp

```html
<tbody>
            <c:forEach var="accident" items="${ACCIDENTS}" varStatus="status">
                <tr>
                    <form action="<c:url value='/edit'/>" method="GET">
                        <td><input type="hidden" name="id" value="${accident.id}">${accident.id}</td>
                        <td><input type="hidden" name="name" value="${accident.name}">${accident.name}</td>
                        <td><input type="hidden" name="text" value="${accident.text}">${accident.text}</td>
                        <td><input type="hidden" name="address" value="${accident.address}">${accident.address}</td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="submit" class="button" name="edit" value="Edit">
                            <input type="submit" class="button" name="delete"  onclick="<c:url value='/delete'/>" method="POST" value="Delete">
                        </td>
                    </form>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
            </tbody>
```

есть контролер -

```html
    @GetMapping("/edit")
    public String edit() {
        return "accident/edit";
    }
    @PostMapping("/delete")
    public String delete(@ModelAttribute Accident accident) {
        accidents.deleteAccident(accident);
        return "redirect:/";
    }
```

как сделать реализацию кнопки delete ?